# VAVR compose Try and List

Tags: java, functional-programming, vavr

I'm trying to figure out what are the idiomatic ways of using VAVR's Try.
The use case I'm looking at has to following steps:
- fetch a list of shoes (the invocation can throw a checked exception)
- clean each shoe (the invocation can throw a checked exception)
- restore each shoe (the invocation can throw a checked exception)
- return a list of cleaned/restored shoes

Here is my sample toy code where processRequest method buys n pairs of shoes, cleans & restores them; prints errors if any:

```
// definitions
ShoeStore java.util.List<Shoe> buy(int numberOfPairs) throws OutOfStockException;
ShoeCleaningService Shoe clean(Shoe dirtyShoe) throws OutOfShoePolishException;
ShoeRestoreService Shoe restore(Shoe oldShoe) throws OutOfSparePartsException;

class EnterpriseShoeService {
    // constructor
    ...

    public List<Shoe> processRequest(int numberOfPairs) {
        Try<List<Shoe>> shoes = Try.of(() -> shoeStore.buy(numberOfPairs));
        Try<List<Try<Shoe>>> cleanedAndRestoredShoes = shoes.map(xs -> xs.stream().map(shoe ->
                Try.success(shoe)
                        .andThenTry(shoeCleaningService::clean)
                        .andThenTry(shoeRestoreService::restore))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        List<Shoe> result = cleanedAndRestoredShoes
                .getOrElseGet(err -> {
                    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                })
                .stream()
                .map(shoeTry -> shoeTry.onFailure(err -> System.out.println(err.getMessage())))
                .filter(Try::isSuccess)
                .map(Try::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return result;

    }
}
```

My question is: how could this logic be simplified? are there any method calls that could be eliminated? could the readability be improved?

Comment: I like the fact that you're presenting a toy example to highlight the issue you are facing, but it's still kind of difficult to reverse engineer from the code, what you're trying to achieve. In addition to posting the code you've ended up with, you could add a list of requirements. Maybe some bullet points what you would like to see if there is an error at the the fetching of shoes, what if there's an error when cleaning/restoring the shoe, and how would you like to aggregate a list of the resulting shoes when there was an error in some of the shoes, but not all of them (short circuiting?).

Comment: I believe you should focus first of interface you would like to have for this solution. 
If there are not enough shoes what should happened ? Is it all or nothing ? You labeled your question as functional-programing - regarding this you should at least split you function to multiple well named functions.

Comment: For example -> Returning type is making no sens since you are filtering only successfull request so List<Try<Shoe>> will only contains List<Success<Shoe>>.
We can remove this Try wrapper from returing type.Type matters in FP - your example is full of compilation errors.

Comment: I already have multiple functions: buy, clean, restore. Now what I'd like to achieve is to compose them in a readable way.

Comment: Something similar to: buy().flatMap(shoes -> shoes.stream).map(shoe -> clean(shoe)).map(shoe->restore(shoe)).collect(list). My motivation is to write a readable solution. In Java, lambda expressions and checked exceptions are awkward to compose so I'm looking at Option(al), Try, Either.

Comment: There is happening a lot. What you have is very complex method which is doing everything. Vavr is used only in this method scope. Maybe for the start try to return Try from buy clean restore methods. It will allow you to clean something.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if everything is working as expected since no requirements were mention but this should give you an idea of power of decomposition.

```
import io.vavr.collection.List;
import io.vavr.control.Try;


public class TryListComposition {

   ShoeStore store;

   ShoeCleaningService cleaningService;

   ShoeRestoreService restoreService;

   public java.util.List<Shoe> processRequest(int numberOfPairs) {
    return processShoesRequest(numberOfPairs).getOrElse(List.empty()).toJavaList();
   }

   public Try<List<Shoe>> processShoesRequest(int numberOfPairs) {
      return this.buy(numberOfPairs)
            .map(shoes -> shoes
                    .map(this::cleanAndRestore)
                    .flatMap(x -> x)
            );
   }

   public Try<Shoe> cleanAndRestore(Shoe shoe) {
      return clean(shoe).flatMap(this::restore);
   }


   Try<List<Shoe>> buy(int numberOfPairs) {
      return Try.of(() -> 
        List.ofAll(store.buy(numberOfPairs).stream());
   }

   Try<Shoe> clean(Shoe dirtyShoe) {
      return Try.of(() -> cleaningService.clean(dirtyShoe));
   }

   Try<Shoe> restore(Shoe oldShoe) {
      return Try.of(() -> restoreService.restore(oldShoe));
   }

}

class Shoe {

}

interface ShoeStore {
   java.util.List<Shoe> buy(int numberOfPairs) throws 
   OutOfStockException;
}

interface ShoeCleaningService {
   Shoe clean(Shoe dirtyShoe) throws OutOfShoePolishException;
}

interface ShoeRestoreService {
   Shoe restore(Shoe oldShoe) throws OutOfSparePartsException;
}

class OutOfStockException extends Exception {

}

class OutOfShoePolishException extends Exception {

}

class OutOfSparePartsException extends Exception {

}
```